# How does Node.js handle interruptions in this scenario?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, threadpool

I want to clear my potential misunderstandings about how Node.js uses processor cores. At first I want to show my current understanding as it might not be correct and there is no point going further down the rabbit hole. Let's see the following code snippet:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const util = require('util')
const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile)

console.log('First sync thing')

readFile('bigFile.txt')
  .then(() => console.log('Done reading bigFile.txt'))

console.log('Second sync thing')
```

Let's say that I have a single core system. I want to do something that might be CPU-intensive without blocking my main thread. I start doing my sync things in the main thread, at one point I start something asynchronous, and then I do some other sync thing. Everything is all right, because the main thread is not blocked, the invociation of readFile returns a promise, creates a thread in the background and will return with the result what will be logged to the console after all the sync things.

It is usually said that a Node.js thread of execution is never interrupted to do something else, it always runs to completion. After running to completion the engine checks the event queue to see if there's something else waiting to be executed, and that is the '.then' handler on the microtask queue in this specific scenario. But if I use a single core system, some interruption somewhere does have to happen, because we actully want the result of the readFile operation, and that is not handled in the main thread. The processor has to manage the reading of the file, so there must be an interruption somewhere to achieve concurrency where the processor handles thread pool threads / kernel commands. If there was absolutely no interruption, and no change to the background thread the main thread would just hang up everything and the script would never finish running. So I suppose that there is an interruption, but that doesn't concern our userland code, so what people usually say about running to completion might mean that our userland code is not being unexpectedly interrupted by another part of our userland code.

If we have multiple cores on the same machine, we can achieve actual parallelism instead of concurrent changing between the userland code and the 'background threads'. If we have multiple multicore machines, we can have multiple Node.js applications run, each dealing with their own 'background threads' paralelly. On top of all these, we can create child processes for every Node.js app to run userland code or specific programs using a different process, and therefore a different thread paralelly. If we have multiple processors, then they can of course work independently, but interruptions have to come into the picture somewhere inside each process. Looking at all above, the notion that a specific Node.js thread runs to completion every time can't hold. There is a contradiction somewhere, because Node.js obviously works, so it's a misunderstanding on my part. Where does the interruption actually happen? Please help me understand this issue.

Comment: This will clarify all of your points https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Comment: The moment you used `then` it jumps over the next line, it's not really a sync process.

Comment: "*the invociation of readFile returns a promise, creates a thread in the background*" - actually, no. The operating system file apis that node.js uses are asynchronous as well.

Comment: "*there must be an interruption somewhere to achieve concurrency where the processor handles thread pool threads / kernel commands*" - processor no, kernel yes. The [preemptive multitasking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemptive_multitasking) you are talking about here is managed by the operating system kernel, not be the processor core. Node.js is just one of many processes running on your single-core machine, but it doesn't care.

Comment: "*what people usually say about running to completion might mean that our userland code is not being unexpectedly interrupted by another part of our userland code*" - yes, precisely. This never states anything about all the other code that is running your computer at the same time, it always concerns the javascript code only.